# Simple Analytical mechanics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames

I am trying to solve a simple problem stated as follows:

> "There are two cartesian reference frames k $(o;x,y,z)$ and K $(O;X,Y,Z)$ with the first one being still (inertial) and the second one (K) with its plane $XY$ that oscillates vertically so that $X$ maintain itself parallel to $x$ and $Y$ maintain itself parallel to $y$; the origin O of K moves along the $z$ axis of k with the law $O = a*cos(k*t)$; a "car" that can be represented as a point $P$ of mass $m$ moves in the K frame along the $X$ axis with constant velocity $v$. When $t = 0$ a stone $S$ of mass $M$ is thrown from the car along the $X$ axis in its positive direction with initial velocity $V$. Considering that on the stone is acting the force of gravity, prove that if $v$ is not equal to $V$ the two masses will never collide again in the future while if $v = V$ the two masses will always collide after a certain period of time $t_0 > 0$, independently of the values of the constants $a$ and $k$".

I thought I have correctly written the equations of motion (both in the frames k and K) of the stone and the car but I struggle proving that if $v = V$ the stone will be able to fall on the car at some point in the future: in the transformation of coordinates from K to k I assumed that the rotation matrix is the identity and that only a translation is present, hence in k the car moves with the laws $x = v*t + x_0$ and $z = a*cos(k*t)$ while the stone moves with the following laws: $x= V*t + x_0$ and $z = -(1/2)*g*t^2 + a$, so how will the $z$ coordinates of the car and the stone ever be the same for $t > 0$? I must be missing something very trivial here. Can anybody point me to the right direction? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The problem question is false***

Let's "c" denote the car and "M" the mass that is thrown from the car. The equations of motion that you found are indeed correct (in the inertial frame, with $x_0=0$):

$$x_c(t)=vt\quad\quad z_c(t)=a\cos(kt)$$
$$x_M(t) = Vt\quad\quad z_M(t)=a-\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2$$

If $V\ne v$ than the x coordinates of the the car and $M$ are never equal (the fastest one is always ahead).

If $V=v$ than the x coordinates are always equal and you only have to prove that there exists a time $t_0$ such that

$$z_c(t_0) = z_M(t_0)$$
which is a solution greater than zero of the equation
$$a-\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2=a\cos(kt)$$

The problem is that this equation doesn't always have a solution, you can graph it with $a=1$ and $k=1$ and you will see that the parabola is all under the cosine function and they are equal in zero.

***When do they meet?***
Let's call
$$f(t)= a\cos(kt)-a+\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2$$
We know $f(0)=0$ and we want to find a condition for the existence of a positive solution. $f(+\infty)=+\infty$. If $f$ decreases after zero it becomes negative, and there has to be a zero between 0 and infinity. This happens when
$$f'(t)<0$$
immediately after zero. We have
$$f'(t)=-ak\sin(kt)+gt=-ak^2t+gt+o(t)$$ using little o notation.

This way we know the derivative is negative immediately after zero when
$$ak^2>g$$

You can also verify this by playing with sliders in desmos:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/voyefnfsr5

Comment: thanks for writing such a detailed answer! This makes sense to me. To give you the context, I downloaded this problem from the web site of the faculty of Physics, University of Rome (link: http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/users/gentile/2020-2021/FM210/esami/Esame5-20202021.pdf). It is in Italian, so apologies if it isn't clear; the problem I was referring to is n. 2, question 6; what seemed strange to me is that the text claims that the solution always exists regardless the values of a and k, which seems not correct (e.g. you proved that the equation does not have a solution if a=k=1)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm Italian too. I think the professor may have made a mistake.
If the anwers is ok remember to accept it (the "V" under the score)